# Is there a way to list or iterate over the CONTENT of a file in S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have a S3 object that has a key

I am trying to iterate over the values of an key inside S3, which is basically a simple **.txt** file. I have found similar questions for iterating over objects and listing files in an object, but nothing so far on iterating over the actual contents of the file itself.

The code below will return the object and bucket containing the data but it doesn't list it's content nor give me an optiopn to iterate over it's contents. This appears to just filter the keys in the object itself, but I am trying to open or/and iterate over the values of the key.

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')  

bucket = s3.Bucket('account-id-metadata')

for i in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='data.txt'):
    print(i)
```

Would like to know if this is possible with S3 using boto3?

**NOTE: This was originally in a local file and & I was planning to iterate over the file locally instead; however, because of the large amount of data it was crashing & taking up a lot of memory, so I moved this to S3 hoping to perform the same functionality.**

Thanks you in advance.

Comment: Unless your file is terabytes in size, have you considered modifying the way your code operates on the file to not require it all to be loaded into memory at once? If your operations are very non-trivial, you might consider actually using some sort of database solution.

Comment: You can use [s3 select](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/s3-glacier-select-sql-reference-select.html) if you only need some specific rows from the file. Also you can `get_object` in parts, rather then entire at once.

Answer (score 0):

The only Amazon S3 operation that works on the "contents" of an object is [S3 Select and Glacier Select – Retrieving Subsets of Objects | AWS News Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/s3-glacier-select/).

This allows you to use SQL-like commands to extract rows and columns from a **single object** for certain file formats. This is useful when wanting to extract a small amount of information from large objects.